# conditional list indexing in R

Tags: r

The output of `strsplit()` can be the following:

```
list( c("a","b") , character(0) , c("a","b") )
```

or, if assigning the expression to `lst`:

```
> lst
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "a" "b"
```

What is the vectorized way to replace the `character(0)` entry? I'm trying to avoid the following:

```
for( i in seq(1,length(lst)) ){
  if (length(lst[[i]]) == 0) {
    lst[[i]] <- "nothing"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
lst[sapply(lst,identical,character(0))] <- 'nothing'
```

Comment: `lst[sapply(lst, length)==0] <- "nothing"` if you want to stick with using `length`